# How can I detect if email subject in mime is decoded on PHP?

Tags: php, decode, mime

How can I check if email subject in mime is decoded on PHP?

I want to decode below string.

```
"=E8=A7=A3=E5=87=8D=E3=83=91=E3=82=B9=E3=83=AF=E3=83=BC=E3=83=89=E9=80=9A==E7=9F=A5=E3=83=A1=E3=83=BC=E3=83=AB / password information for the zip fil=e"
```

I tried to catch it using below but it passed.

```
preg_match_all('/=\?(?:(?!\?=).)*\?=/is' , $var , $matches);

if( 0 < count($matches[0]) ){
    echo "catched.";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `echo quoted_printable_decode ( $yourstring );` returns a reasonable string - if [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&op=translate) works…